# R single element subsetting (aka `[[`) using a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset

Assuming, I'm understanding the documentation of `[[` correctly, a matrix can be used to subset a `data.frame`:

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector. Negative indices are not allowed in the index matrix. NA and zero values are allowed: rows of an index matrix containing a zero are ignored, whereas rows containing an NA produce an NA in the result.

While this works for `[`, I'm struggling to understand how to do this with `[[`.

```r
mtcars[1:6, 1:6]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460
(ind <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2))
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    4
#> [2,]    2    5
#> [3,]    3    6
mtcars[ind]
#> [1] 110.00   3.90   2.32
mtcars[[ind]]
#> Error in as.matrix(x)[[i]]: attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Is this a bug? Or am I misinterpreting the documentation?

Here is the source of `[[.data.frame` (v3.6.1)

```r
function (x, ..., exact = TRUE)
{
    na <- nargs() - !missing(exact)
    if (!all(names(sys.call()) %in% c("", "exact")))
        warning("named arguments other than 'exact' are discouraged")
    if (na < 3L)
        (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i))
            as.matrix(x)[[i]]
        else .subset2(x, i, exact = exact))(x, ..., exact = exact)
    else {
        col <- .subset2(x, ..2, exact = exact)
        i <- if (is.character(..1))
            pmatch(..1, row.names(x), duplicates.ok = TRUE)
        else ..1
        col[[i, exact = exact]]
    }
}
```

Comment: **The [[ form allows only a single element to be selected using integer or character indices,....**

Comment: @NelsonGon Could you please explain how my question is a duplicate of the linked question? I'm well aware of the general differences between `[` and `[[`. I'm asking, whether it's possible to subset a `data.frame` using `[[` and a matrix for indexing. Could you tell me where exactly this is answered in the linked question. I could not find anything relating to my exact question.

Comment: Hello, sorry I normally link to a possible duplicate and if OP or someone else thinks it's a duplicate then it is closed. While you need to use a matrix for indexing, R's `[[` only supports single elements hence you can not use `[[` which is what the linked question states. You might conceptually map your matrix indices to `[[` and use that. I'm sorry if you found it offensive to close your well worded question.

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm not offended. I simply don't see how you are helping my question. Your only argument is a sentence from R-lang, which I don't see as an answer. In some sense, what I propose is exactly what R-lang says on the topic: I'm selecting elements using numeric indices.

Comment: Alright, I might be wrong but subsetting `1:6` and `1:6` is different from a matrix built with `1:6` and 2 columns. In any case, what is the actual use case like? I mean there are several alternative ways to subset.

Comment: @NelsonGon could you please undo the closing of my question? Clearly you are wrong in claiming that there is no provision for subsetting a `data.frame` with a matrix using `[[`.

Comment: I voted to reopen. I think it needs some votes, hopefully someone with more "power" can reopen it. Frankly I sometimes don't vote on duplicates to avoid issues such as this. I don't want to be right or wrong, I actually prefer being wrong since I'm here to learn.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The doc page (`?Extract`) you reference says that arrays can be indexed by matrices. Implicitly, I take that to mean non-arrays *cannot* be indexed by matrices. Data frames are not arrays, so they cannot be indexed by matrices. (Matrices are arrays, of course.)

---

I do think you're misinterpreting the documentation. You're looking at a documentation page that jointly documents `[`, `[[`, and `$`, together. In the argument description, it says

> When indexing arrays by `[` a single argument `i` can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of `x`...

The section you quote at the top of your question comes later on, under the heading Matrices and Arrays, which I take to be a section about *subsetting* matrices and arrays, not about using matrices as indices. (Look at the rest of the section, and the sections before and after, and I think you'll agree with me.)

Nowhere on that documentation page does it talk about using matrices as indices **for `[[`**.

I'm surprised it's handled specially in the `[[` code you show - but near as I can tell, a matrix given to `[[.data.frame` will error out unless it's a 1x1 matrix, in which case the data frame is treated as a matrix and the single element is returned, for some arcane reason (probably "compatability with S", though I've no good guess as to why S would allow it).